# overiding NumberFormat in .net application cultureInfo

Tags: .net, cultureinfo, number-formatting

I have a .NET application available in several different language. i basically load and save file  (containing doubles) in the System Culture but i would like to force numbers to always be displayed and entered using the US culture format (comma as digit grouping, period as decimal separator). I tried to override the application Culture but it doesn't seem to work.
Is there a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` exists for the specific purpose of persisting data in a consistent format. [More Info on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a.aspx)

For the UI, if you really want all formatting to be US-style, you can do this:

```
Application.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Note that you would need to set the culture on each thread.

Comment: Would it break the UI if i set Application.CultureInfo = InvariantCulture?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood you. The purpose of InvariantCulture would be to store the doubles in a culture-agnostic way; it should not be used for the UI. For that, I would set Application.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US").